# :hover isn't working with styled 'a' tag

Tags: html, css

I had the a:hover mechanism working until I implemented the :active, :visited and :link methods to prevent the link from changing colour upon click etc, please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```css
#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:hover {
    color: #696969;
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:visited {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:active {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:link {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to have `#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a`, since `#textContainer` will be the only instance of this element. You should really just be using `#textContainer h2 a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your order of pseudo-classes completely mixed up.

The order is `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active` (also known by the mnemonic "LoVe-HAte") See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

```css
#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:link {
    color: #b3b3b3;    
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:visited {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:hover {
    color: #696969;
}

#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:active {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Comment: And for that matter, you don't need so many ID selectors unless your markup is so unpredictable and messy that those IDs could appear in different elements across different pages.

Comment: +1 for the order, I didn't know that. It seems a bit unnecessary to re-declare `:link`, `:visited` and `:active` if you could just declare them all in `a`, and only change `:hover`.

Comment: @Wex: If you only want a different style for hover... yes, you *can* just style `a` and override in `a:hover`. That's what I do sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the a:hover declaration so that it is after the :visited declaration.  The problem is that each selector has the same [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
#header #navigation #textContainer h2 a:hover {
    color: #696969!important;
}
```

I'm guessing the :hover color gets overwritten by the other definitions.

Comment: Your guess is correct. While your suggestion is not incorrect, it's simply unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `a` will actually set `a:hover`, `a:visited`, `a:active`, and `a:link`. You should really only have to set `a:hover` if that's the only color you want to change.

Comment: Not quite... a rule with `a` as its selector isn't going to override any preceding `a:...` rules. All it does is set general styles for `a` elements - it's not a shorthand for all four state pseudo-classes.

Comment: I'm not saying it will override preceding rules, I'm saying that you shouldn't be using the other rules if you're not changing the `a` state.